# How to make an imitation of apple.com cart

Tags: javascript

I would really love to make a left menu like apples shopping-cart.
What's unique is that it stays static while you scoll down but don't move over header, when you go back to top. And there is no easing (which take too much attention).

I allready use mootools on the site, so if the solution is adaptable to mootools...I'll give a hug :-)

Comment: Do you mean this? http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/